# Mysql query optimization issue

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am facing an query optimizing problem. Hope I will get some help.
The scenario is I have 4 tables.

```
Table 1 [asset_id, asset_name, User_id].
Table 2 [company_id, Company_name]
Table 3 [User_id, User_name]
Table 4 [Map_id, User_id, Company_id ]
```

My result will be to check Users from same company cannot able to upload same asset, checking of asset will be on COmpany level.
I have already written a query, that serves the purpose as well, but i need to eliminate the sub query for optimizing purpose.
The query I have written has a sub query.
My query is

```
SELECT COUNT(tg.asset_id) 
  FROM Table 1 tg 
 INNER JOIN Table 4 mcu 
    ON ((tg.User_id = mcu.User_id  )
   AND mcu.Company_id = (select Table 4.Company_id 
                           from Table 4 
                          where Table 4.User_id = 1))
WHERE tg.asset_name = 't1' ;
```

Comment: Please post the query as well.

Comment: yes I forgot to do that

Comment: You didn't use Table 2 and 3. Did you missed something?

Comment: Please paste the explain plan i.e., the prefix the query with EXPLAIN and run it, and paste the result

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may be helpful::

```
SELECT 
COUNT(tg.asset_id) 
FROM Table 1 tg
INNER JOIN Table 4 mcu ON (tg.User_id = mcu.User_id and Company_id = ClientID )

WHERE tg.asset_name = 't1' and mcu.User_id = 1
```

Comment: please check the query once as i have edited the query
Here what is needed, that it should check the is a particular assets has already been uploaded by a user of the same company

Answer (score -1):

The subquery seems unneeded for this query since it also uses Table 4.

```
SELECT COUNT(tg.asset_id) FROM Table 1 tg 
INNER JOIN Table 4 mcu ON tg.User_id = mcu.User_id
WHERE tg.asset_name = 't1'
AND mcu.ClientID = mcu.Company_id
AND mcu.User_id = 1;
```

Comment: Here what is needed, that it should check the is a particular assets has already been uploaded by a user of the same company

Comment: I mean that you didn't need that subquery since it also refers from Table 4. You can just include the conditions in the main query.

Comment: please check the my query in the question once as i have edited the query